# SAVING Flash (AS3) data to XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, export

I've been all over the interwebs, including Stack Overflow, for hours, trying to identify a solid, workable example of saving information in Flash into an XML file.

I want to take the positions of two different types of objects and export the lists of each to XML. We'll call the objects **ball** and **bat**.

So, I'd love to have the XML look something like:

```
<objects>
    <ball xPos=34 yPos=43/>
    <ball xPos=12 yPos=94/>
    <bat xPos=1 yPos=39/>
</objects>
```

Sounds simple enough, but I haven't been able to find a single decent example for exactly what AS3 code can accomplish this. The data is in two vectors of MovieClips, so I'd be using bats[i].x and bats[i].y for input values.

How can I create this XML, and save it somewhere local to view? Thank you for any help at all, this has proved extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Working with XML in AS3 is really easy, so to expand on TheDarkIn1978's answer with some code:

Creating an XML object:

```
var objs:XML = new XML( <objects /> ); // create the <objects /> node

// for your objects
var ball1:XML = new XML ( <ball /> ); // create the <ball /> node
ball1.@xPos = 12; // add 12 as an attribute named "xPos"
ball1.@yPos = 42; // add 42 as an attribute named "yPos"
objs.appendChild( ball1 ); // add the <ball> node to <objects>

// an example of using variables in your xml
var name:String = "something";
var sx:XML = new XML( <{name} /> ); // creates a node <something />
```

Use the TheDarkIn1978's to the `XML` class in AS3 to learn more.

Saving out your file:

```
// saving out a file
var f:FileReference = new FileReference;
f.save( sx, "myXML.xml" ); // saves under the name myXML.xml, "sx" being your root XML node
```

Compressing your XML before saving (with large XML files, this can save a lot):

```
// compressing before saving
var f:FileReference = new FileReference;

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
bytes.writeUTFBytes( myXML ); // "myXML" being your root XML node
bytes.compress(); // compress it

f.save( bytes, "myXML.xml" );
```

Loading in a compressed XML, uncompressing it, and retrieving the XML object:

```
// uncompressing a compressed xml
var loader = new URLLoader;
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

// listen for our events
loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this._onLoad );
loader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this._onFail ); // not shown
loader.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, this._onSecurityError ); // not shown

private function _onLoad( e:Event ):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;

    // get the data as a bytearray
    var ba:ByteArray = loader.data as ByteArray;

    // uncompress it
    try
    {
        ba.uncompress();
    }
    catch ( e:Error )
    {
        trace( "The ByteArray wasn't compressed!" );
    }

    // get our xml data
    myXML = XML( ba );
}
```

I created a simple tool for compressing/uncompressing XML files. You can get the SWF and source at http://divillysausages.com/blog/xml_compressor_uncompressor if you're interested

Comment: That was absolutely fantastic, thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Comment from user @Lional: "I saw this page about saving as XML. It works perfectly.

But a little mistake is in the page.

they are 

    var 'f':FileReference = new FileReference;
    file.save( 'myXML', "myXML.xml" ); // saves under the name myXML.xml, "myXML" being y

please change f as file.

And `"myXML" as "sx"`. where i quote `'f', 'myXML'`" . (*Copied from soon-to-be-deleted answer*).

Comment: @CraigRinger Ha, can't believe I didn't see that. Changed; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript 3.0 is built with [E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html), so you can create XML objects at runtime and then write them to disk as text files (with .xml extension, of course).

if you're programming for browser-resident Flash, you can use [flash.net.FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html), but this approach presents a dialog window to load/save files.  if you're programming in AIR you can load/save files as background processes using [flash.fileSystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

i'm assuming you are programming for the browser and would like to handle the data in the background.  in this case, you also have the (very common) option of using a *Local Shared Object* to store and retrieve your XML data object.

more here (including sample code):  [flash.net.SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

Comment: Awesome, I ended up using File Reference and getting it to work. However, it doesn't have real XML spacing, it's just tags following tags with two spaces in between. Any idea how I can force new lines/tabbing in AS3 for that XML? Or is that even necessary?

Comment: try using `myXML.toXMLString();`

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier in some instances to just create a string in as3 and then cast it as xml at the end:

```
import flash.geom.Point;   
var cordiantes = [new Point(34,12),new Point(14,2), new Point(10,15)];

var objects = ["ball","ball","bat"];

// starting the object node.    
var myXmlStr = "<objects>";

for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{

  // adding things to the string between the object nodes.
  myXmlStr += "<" + objects[i] +  " xPos= '" + cordiantes[i].x + "' yPos='" + cordiantes[i].y + "' />";
}

// closing the objects node. 
myXmlStr += "</objects>";


// turning the string into xml.
var xmlfinal:XML = XML(myXmlStr);

trace(xmlfinal);
```

Output is:

```
<objects>
  <ball xPos="34" yPos="12"/>
  <ball xPos="14" yPos="2"/>
  <bat xPos="10" yPos="15"/>
</objects>
```

This would make it easy to make changes and add attributes to the objects later.

also if you're using an array of movieclips it gets even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to divillysausages' answer (that I upvoted).

If you want to add a value to the xml tag, like:

```
<ball>red ball</ball>
```

You can use:

```
var ball:XML = <ball />.appendChild("red ball");
```

Obviously you can pass to appendChild a String variable.